# Obtain the $K$ matrix based on this

Tags: matrices

I have this series of operations. How can I obtain the matrix?

$$
K := E_{12}(27) \cdot E_{13}(2) \cdot E_{15}(7) \cdot E_{23}(23) \cdot E_{45}(3) \cdot E_{41}(12) \cdot E_{52}(2).
$$

I tried to multiply from right to left (starting with the matrix I listed below). But I don't obtain the matrix I need.

I want to check with you if this is right:

$$ E_{52}(2)=\left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1&0&0&0&0 \\
     0&1&0&0&0 \\
     0&0&1&0&0 \\
     0&0&0&1&0\\
     0&2&0&0&1
  \end{array} \right]
$$

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that your $E$'s are elementary matrices. 
So, $E_{52}(2)$ is as you have (put "2" in the $(5,2)$ position of the identity matrix $I$).

But this is just a guess... You should refer to your text/notes for the definition of the $E$'s.

Note that if the $E$'s are as described above, then
multiplication of $A$ by one of these on the left (i.e., $EA$) corresponds to a row operation on $A$ (the same row operation needed to obtain $E$ from $I$).

Using this,
you can compute $K$ in a manner less prone to arithmetic errors.

Comment: Yes, E's are elementary matrices. I don't have an A. I have only these ones. So I should start with the $E_{52}(2)$ right? Instead of A

Comment: Yes. Then multiply on the left by $E_{41}(12)$. So just take $E_{52}(2)$ and add 12 times row 1 to row 4.